# Book that covers abstract and Linear Algebra

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I am trying to buy new books for algebra.

I was wondering,

Is there a book, which covers both linear algebra as well as abstract algebra? Can somebody please let me know of one?

Comment: What specific topics in linear and abstract algebra? How in-depth?

Comment: Dummit and Foote

Comment: @Johanna, I would like in depth, matrices, ranks, eigenvalue etc.. and for abstract algebra, ring theory etc..

Comment: Artin's Algebra !

Comment: Chapter $0$ by Aluffi just to add to the pile.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in both linear and abstract algebra, Abstract Linear Algebra by Morton Curtis & Paul Place might be appealing to you. It's rather concise though, and focused on theory rather than applications.

Answer (score 0):

Peter Cameron's Introduction to Algebra is a really good basic book that covers all that material. It has the advantage of being shorter and cheaper than Dummit and Foote, or Artin.